# CoreData basics – to-many relationship array data

Tags: iphone, core-data

As I am fairly new to CoreData and coming from a MySQL-DB background, the CoreData Moddeling is kind of hard to understand at some point. I am sure you can help me out with this basic question.

[image: CoreData modeling]

CoreData model-descripton:
My database-model basically consists of two entities. The first one is called "Manager", the second one is called "Zipcodes". The "Manager" has 3 attributes, which are negligible at the moment. The important thing in my opinion is here the relationship called "zipcodes". The "Zipcodes"-Entity has an attribute called zip, which is a 16 int. It has a relationship as well, called "manager".

No I'll get to the point: Each manager has multiple zicodes in which he is responsible for all sales. The problem is now that I've setup an manager entity and want to link multiple ziplcodes to him. The zipcodes per manager are seperated in one comma seperated string. (12345,56789,...)

First of all I am creating an Manager Entity.

```
Manager *manager = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manager" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

The next step is seperating all zicodes to an array.

```
Manager *manager = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manager" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

NSArray *zipcodesArray = [[dict objectForKey:@"zipcodes"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

for (NSString *zip in zipcodesArray) {
     ???
}
```

So now that's the point where I am stuck. As later on I have to check the zipcodes via a searchBar they should be separated in the database. Do I now have to create a managedObjectModel for each zipcode? How do I connect all of them with the "one" manager entity? I'am sure there is a way to achieve that but I don't really know how.

Hopefully my question is understandable. If there's anything you would like to know, feel free to ask.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (NSString *zip in zipcodesArray) {
  NSManagedObject* zipcode = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName:@"Zipcode" 
                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
  [zipcode setValue:zip forKey:@"zip"];
  [zipcode setValue:manager forKey:@"manager"];
}
```

By establishing the relation from the zipcode to the manager on the last line, Core Data will automatically take care of inserting the zipcode into the relation from the manager back to the zipcodes.

Comment: Ahh the other way round. I always thought of manager and zipcode in kind of a hirachy. So I thought I have to make the connection from manager -> zipcode. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it! By the way, can I update an entity relationship afterwards?

Comment: There is no "afterwards" really. Every time you set the manager field of a zipcode the relation (in both directions) is updated. By the way, you can also modify the other end of the relation if you prefer. In that case, you want to do `NSMutableSet* zipCodes = [manager mutableSetValueForKey:@"zipcodes"];` after which you can modify the mutable set to modify the set of zip codes associated with the manager (and again, the inverse relation from the zipcode to the manager will be set automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Create a managed object instance of `Zipcode`. Set that object's `zip` attribute to the value of the string from your `zipcodesArray`. When you're done, save the managed object to your data store, check for errors, and repeat until you've walked all the way through your zip code array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but how do I connect all of the zipcode managed object instances to the manager managed object? later on I should be able to search through all zipcodes and find the appropriate manager.

Comment: It looks like edsko wrote the code equivalent of my answer. Take a look at that.