# CoreData BEGINSWITH to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data, predicate

CoreData so far is really great :-) I really get into it.
Now I've got a to-many relationship and want to filter that. I'am stuck here. I have multiple zipcodes for example (44512, 12445, ...)
The problem is, if I search for `445` and I use `contains = %@` it returns two results (12345, 12445).

I want to get exactly one result, the result should begin with my searchstring. So normally I would use `BEGINSWITH = %@`. With a to-many relationship I can't use that. Is there any workaround? :-)

Thanks a lot for you help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: how do you store your zip codes ? keypath don't work ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here you can find a screenshot of the db-modeling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846623/coredata-basics-to-many-relationship-array-data As I am new to CoreData I've never used a keypath here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code I can't completely give an answer. Given your other SO question it looks like your Zips are stored as NSStrings.
So, you can construct an NSPredicate and use `beginswith`like in this [example from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html). The `beginswith` example is in the Arrays section but you can easily change the predicate for your example and apply it to your NSFetchRequest. If you've never done a predicate before, the NSFetchRequest has a `predicate` property. You create the predate, then assign it to the NSFetchRequest's predicate property and then execute your fetch request.

Like I said at the beginning, if you show a code snippet we can be more helpful/specific in our answers.